# React - Send param using axios to back-end

Tags: reactjs, parameters, routes, backend

I am working on a project with various get methods.
one of the methods is a get a coupon by `maximum` price which required a `param` to be send from server.

**Get Method from backend:**

```
 @GetMapping("coupon/{price}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public List<Coupon> getCustomerCouponsByMaxPrice(@RequestParam double price) {
        return customerService.getCustomerCouponsByMaxPrice(price);
    }
```

its a very simple method to get all coupons of client by maximum price entered. this method works just fine on backend.

My issue comes on my react component.

**GetComponent on react side:**

```
interface RouteParam {
    price: string;
}

interface CouponByPrice extends RouteComponentProps<RouteParam> { }

interface CouponDetailState {
    coupons: CouponModel[];
}

class GetCouponByPrice extends Component<CouponByPrice, CouponDetailState> {
    public constructor(props: CouponByPrice) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            coupons: null,
        };
    }

    public async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const price = +this.props.match.params.price;
            
          
           // const coupon = store.getState().couponState.coupons.find((p) => p.price === price);
             const response = await axios.get<CouponModel[]>(globals.urls.customerCouponsByPrice + 1000);
            
            this.setState({ coupons: response.data });
        } catch (err) {
            notify.error(err);
        }
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (

            
            <div className="CatDetails Box">
                {!this.state.coupons && <EmptyView msg="No Coupons for that price" />}
                {this.state.coupons && (
                    <>
                        {" "}
                        <h2>CouponByPrice</h2>

                        <div className="top">
                            <h1>Coupon List</h1>
                        </div>/
                        <div className="card">
                            <Box m={4} pt={4} >
                                <Grid container spacing={6}
                                    direction="row"
                                    justifyContent="space-evenly"
                                    alignItems="center"
                                    style={{ minHeight: '80vh' }}
                                >
                                    {
                                        this.state.coupons.map(c => (
                                            <Grid item xs={6} sm={4} >
                                                <Card2 key={c.id} coupon={c} />
                                            </Grid>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                </Grid>
                            </Box>
                        </div>

                        <br />
                        <NavLink to="/home">Back</NavLink>
                    </>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default GetCouponByPrice;
```

**Note:**
I gave an embedded price just to see if it works.

**URL used for axios:**

```
"http://localhost:8080/api/customer/coupon/{param}"
```

I am not sure of the correct syntax for this. however, when I go over code I am not sure on what exactly I am missing.

**ERROR:** I am getting is of `400`.

Still new to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send a config object in your request, which takes a params object.

Try the following

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/customer/coupon/',
  params:{price:'100'}
})
```

See - https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config

Comment: I have tried your method, However, I get the same result. Not sure on why I get `404` response.

Comment: Do you get the result when you hit the API from something like Postman or CURL?

Comment: I fixed it with adding `{param}` to URL and changed `price='100'` to `price:'100'`. Was all a matter of syntax. thanks alot.